# How to avoid installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team System Database Edition to be able to build DBPro projects on a centralized build server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, teamcity

I have a DBPro (DataDude) project inside my solution to manage and version the database schema of my application. I use TeamCity 4.0 for continuous integration.

To be able to build a .dbproj, MSBuild tasks and their respective assemblies have to be installed, other .dbschema and .xsd dependencies put in place. The easiest solution is to install VS2008 TS: Database Edition on the build server.. **something i'd love to avoid.** I have started putting the files in place one by one bot got bored after the build failed on some missing XSD files installed by VSTSDB.

Has anyone found an easy way to avoid installing VSTSDB? A community-made 'redist' installer that puts the right files in the right place and the right assemblies into the GAC? The topic is pretty hard to google so I am hoping to tap the stack overflow knowledge base :)

I am aware of the Deploy folder and vsdbcmd.exe but I would like to build (and deploy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not according to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/15ee69c1-27a7-43b1-a0c6-3adf0d772c28/) by Gert Drapers

Comment: Darn, if that were true, then Microsoft can't fend off accusations of considering this as a license trap.

Comment: While I don't think that's the motivation behind it, I sure hope moving to support agile methodologies means that Continuous Integration among others will be respected in future products.

Answer (score 0):

The question is if you are able to build the db using command line (like devenv.exe with some arguments)? If so I see no problem installing the dev environment and executing through a command line task in MSBuild on the build servers. I do the same thing for MSI installers in the projects I manage.